# Display the numbers in the Y Axis - ASP.NET Chart

Tags: asp.net, charts

I need to display the range on the y Axis where it starts in 0 and going all the way down to 60.

I can easily set 60 (Maximum) to 0 (Minimum) and 0 (Maximum) to -60 (Minimum) but I can't find a way to display 0 as the Maximum and 60 as the Minimum.

I thought to set the Maximum of the Y Axis to 0, the Minimum to -60 and the Interval to 1, and then, somehow changing the style of the text of each mark to Abs(value).

Can anyone thing of some way to to it?

Many thanks in advance,

Elad

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.isreversed.aspx

Just set it to be reversed, this should do what you want if I understand your question correctly.